# Find if a entry has negative value in any column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> ```
> OBJECTID  E201701 G201701 E201702 G201702 E201703 G201703 E201704 G201704 
>       1         2      5      6        5       -1      NaN     6        5
> ```

I want to find if a particular entry (i.e. objectid) has negative value in any of variable (e201701, etc). I tried;

```
IF(AND(B2>0,C2>0,D2>0,E2>0,F2>0,G2>0,H2>0),1,0)
```

but it just give me 1 irrespective.

Comment: `>0` means *greater than zero* not *less than zero*. You want `<0`

Comment: what happens if there's more than one negative value ?

Comment: More that one negative also means its a invalid entry and need to be market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is asking "Is thisCell > (Greater than) thisCell?" Try using this. Also, change the AND to an OR because `AND` is going to check all values and if `ALL` of them are returning true then it will return as such. `OR` will check `EACH` individually.

`IF(OR(B2<0,C2<0,D2<0,E2<0,F2<0,G2<0,H2<0),1,0)`
Which is asking "Is thisCell > (Less than) thisCell?"

Comment: Might want to change that And to an Or (and maybe even explain why to the op) *'has negative value in **any** of variable'*

Comment: @Jeeped I think I described that correctly? I don't have excel open right now so I'm just going based off logic. Feel free to explain if I did a crap job, which is likely.

Comment: I played tried both ><. Your OR suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use excel 2013 or later then you can use below formula. This formula will also give you position number where the negative value is. As your sample data it will return `6` because negative value is in 6th position.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:I1)/(A1:I1<0),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For sample same results as @xTwisteDx but shorter and easy to extend (eg to include `G201704` just change `H` to `I`) :

```
=1*(MIN(B2:H2)<0)
```